# Reusability of @ApiResponse Annotation in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am using Swagger annotations to document API in non-spring context.
I find that response documentation for 400, 401 and 404 is reusable.
Since it takes around 8 lines to document each response code as shown below.

```
    @Operation(
            summary = "getDetails",
            description = "someDescription",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "200",
                            description = "Found",
                            content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema =  @Schema(
                                            name = "Response for success")
                            )
                    ),
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "400",
                            description = "Validation failure on inputs.",
                            content = @Content(
                                    mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema = @Schema(
                                            name = "Response For Bad Request")
                            )
                    ),
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "404",
                            description = "Not found",
                            content = @Content(
                                    mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema = @Schema(
                                            name = "Response For Not Found Request")
                            )

                    ),
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "401",
                            description = "Unauthorized",
                            content = @Content(
                                    mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema = @Schema(
                                            name = "Response For Unauthorized")
                            )
                    )
            }
    )
```

I intend to prevent bloating the lines for each reusable API response.
I would prefer something like below

```
  @Operation(
            summary = "getDetails",
            description = "someDescription",
            responses = {
                   @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "200",
                            description = "Found",
                            content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema =  @Schema(
                                            name = "Response for success")
                            )
                    ),
                    SomeStaticClass.getBadResponseDesc(),
                    SomeStaticClass.getUnauthorizedResponseDesc()
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in java 8?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `globalResponseMessage` on the `Docket` object.  See [point 22](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#configuration-explained) on the springfox documentation for an example of their use.  I used this approach to remove a lot of `@ApiResponse` annotations from my code.